Expo Router Link Failing After Navigating via Link Back & Forth 3 Times (iOS fails silently & Android crashes w "specified child already has parent")
Step 1:
Click on the following on the Login page:
  <Pressable style={styles.button}>
    <Link href='/register' style={styles.link}>
      <Text>Don't have an account?{'\n'}Register</Text>
    </Link>
  </Pressable>

Result 1:
This takes me to the Register page (as intended).
Step 2:
Click on the following on the Register page:
  <Pressable style={styles.button}>
    <Link href='/login' style={styles.link}>
      <Text>Have an account?{'\n'}Login</Text>
    </Link>
  </Pressable>

Result 2:
This takes me back to the Login page (as intended).
Step 3:
Repeat Step 1 (click on the Register Link).
Result 3 (iOS):
In the iPhone Simulator, this takes me back to the Register page (as intended).
Step 4 (iOS):
Repeat Step 2 (click on the Login Link).
Result 4 (iOS):
This does absolutely nothing. The Link is no longer functional.
Result 3 (Android):
App crashes and shows error: "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

I am using Metro Bundler and Expo Go.
Another interesting clue is that the issue does not occur when running on the web.
I am developing with the following versions of Expo, Expo-Router, and React-Native:
"expo": "~52.0.18",
"expo-router": "4.0.11",
"react-native": "0.76.5",

The following questions seem to be related but they either don't have good answers:
React Native: The specified child already has a parent
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first react native
...or both the question and answer are Android-specific and I couldn't decipher anything that seemed to be relevant for the context of React Native and/or Expo development:
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first (Android)
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first”
android:The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()

The current workaround I've found is to add the push prop like so:
  <Pressable style={styles.button}>
    <Link push href='/register' style={styles.link}>
      <Text>Don't have an account?{'\n'}Register</Text>
    </Link>
  </Pressable>

...that I found here in the Expo Router docs. I initially tried using the replace prop but that caused me to lose my back button in the Stack headers.
I'm glad that this is resolving my issue and I hope that it helps others, but I would also greatly appreciate if anyone could explain this problem so that I have a better understanding of why it is happening and why my 'solution' is working.
